# Remember the one liner code challenges?

Tags: computer-science, history, code-golf

Does anyone remember years ago in magazines like Byte where people competed to produce the most functional piece of code written in a single line of code?  I remember games like Pole Position with scrollng text, etc. and fractal graphics being done this way.

Granted modern languages like C# and Java an endless amount in one statement, does anyone know of anything similar going on now?  It was also inspiring and interesting stuff to see.

Comment: I'm a fan of the oneliner emacs command:  M-x do-my-job-for-me

Comment: Don't we have Programming puzzles and Code golf here on SE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a site called [Code Golf](http://codegolf.com/) dedicated to competing on problems in that format.

Answer (score 2):

[Code Golf on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) is a great for these types of challenges

Answer (score 2):

There is [**commandlinefu.com**](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/browse) -- good to type quickly on the **`shell`**.
But, I like **`code`** written to be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Check out any of the questions here tagged '[code-golf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)' for some interesting stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess technically, you could write almost anything as one line of code if the language ignored white space.

Maybe some sort of HTML or web app?

How about a gigantic blob of C code?

Comment: Most folks would consider "a = b; c = d;" to be *two* lines of C code, even though they may be on the same textual line.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't consider that a very good exercise, as functional languages like Lisp are going to have an inherent advantage.

The old joke about APL is that you can write an entire OS in one line, but nobody could read it.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net) and solve the problems one-by-one, the forums will have people trying to code-golf their solutions. (i.e for [Problem 1](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=1), got to this [forum](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=forum&id=1))